# Android App XML multiple screen support

Tags: android, xml, screen, resolution

I made a calculator app and used density independent pixels to create the layout, place the buttons and so on. Yet on a tablet emulator it doesnt display correctly, it only takes about 1/4 of the screen. On my phone(800x480) everything is ok. How can I adress this issue?

Comment: Have you provided the appropriate drawable folders and properly scaled images?

Comment: I don't use any images, just the basic buttons from the graphical layout editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide additional layout folders for the different screen sizes so that the Android system doesn't use the same one by default, resulting in the behavior you've described.

This is accomplished by adding layout folders with size specifiers such as: small, medium, large and xlarge.

`layout-small` is an example.

So, to be clear, you're adding additional *folders* for the different supported screen sizes. You'll then add a layout of the *same* name to each folder you add. The system handles the headache.

You would then alter the layout to achieve the best results. Note that it is common practice, when dealing with larger screen sizes, to provide more content on a single screen as opposed to blowing everything up. If your app can benefit from that, it looks better than having obscenely large buttons stringing across the screen, IMHO.

For a complete run down, please refer to [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: So in the layout folder I need to add layout-small, normal, large and so on folders? But where in the layout do I state how big the resolution is? Also can I name them all the same or how do I know which layout to open from the activity?

Comment: The beauty is you don't have to. The system determines the best to use based on the device; same as images when done this way. The name of each layout will be the same, so when you code your activity you simply use that name, the system handles the rest. It's only the folder name that is different - key point.